# VSTS - Azure end point issue

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, endpoints

I am currently getting the following error on VSTS when trying to do publish a release to a Azure:

*The release definition cannot be saved because the environment 'App-Service-Template' references a service endpoint that is in dirty state. Update the endpoint(s) and retry the operation. Details: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'*

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps and still get the same error:

- I have recreated the service end point in VSTS and it fails
- I have recreated the Resource group in Azure that the service point connects to and have tried to connect the end point to a empty resource group and it fails
- I followed the manual steps of creating the end point connection, i then can verify the status of the connection which passes. I then try to publish the release to Azure and get the above error message.
- Lastly i have tried all the MS VSTS recommended troubleshooting with still no luck https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=vsts

I am all out of ideas. Any Help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Do you try it with a new release definition?

Comment: Yes, have tried it with a new definition, with the same result.

Comment: Try to create a new team project and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ultimately fixed this issue for us was abandoning and deleting the failed releases, and then a new build and release triggered from that new build.

(one weird quirk we encountered was that the release sat in the last stage for over 8 minutes: 'wait for console output from agent'... when I left the release and came back it said successful with the last stage only taking 27 seconds)

We had the exact same error. I also ran through the points on your list with no luck, before arriving at the solution with a new build and release.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve the issue. It was caused by a corrupt resource group in Azure. Deleted the resource group and created it with a different name and this worked. No idea why this happened as there were no logs and resources where running in the group, just couldn't deploy new or change existing ones.

Comment: Strange! We recently migrated our app services over from a different resource group so we've had builds fail due to inaccurate resource groups already as well. VSTS could at least improve the error message for us... 'dirty state' doesn't really tell us much!